# How to get the public ip's using boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I need to extract all the RUNNING PUBLIC Ip's from AWS and i am using the following code:

```
def gather_public_ip():
    regions = ['us-west-2', 'eu-central-1', 'ap-southeast-1']
    combined_list = []   ##This needs to be returned
    for region in regions:
        instance_information = [] # I assume this is a list, not dict
        ip_dict = {}
        client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                              region_name=region, )
        instance_dict = client.describe_instances().get('Reservations')
        for reservation in instance_dict:
            for instance in reservation['Instances']: # This is rather not obvious
               if instance[unicode('State')][unicode('Name')] == 'running' and instance[unicode('PublicIpAddress')] != None:
                    ipaddress = instance[unicode('PublicIpAddress')]
                    tagValue = instance[unicode('Tags')][0][unicode('Value')] # 'Tags' is a list, took the first element, you might wanna switch this
                    zone = instance[unicode('Placement')][unicode('AvailabilityZone')]
                    info = ipaddress, tagValue, zone
                    instance_information.append(info)
        combined_list.append(instance_information)
    return combined_list
```

This is not working out for me , and it gives me the error :

```
    ipaddress = instance[unicode('PublicIpAddress')]
KeyError: u'PublicIpAddress'
```

The reason being `PublicIpAddress` doesn't exists in this dict.. Can someone please help me out ?

Comment: I think the `'PublicIpAddress'` is not always returned. Can you add a `print instance` just before `ipaddress = instance[unicode('PublicIpAddress')]` and show the result?

Comment: It's unrelated to your issue, but in most versions of Python (all but 3.0-3.2) you can write Unicode literals with a `u` prefix, (`u'whatever'`) rather than using the `unicode` constructor.

Comment: @AbdulFatir yes you are indeed right, this is not being returned always since most of the IP's are private and do not have a public IP. I need to pass a check on it before printing it up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `get()` instead of `dict[key]`. `get()` will not raise a `KeyError`. Here are some examples which will explain.

```
>>> test = {'xxx':123}
>>> test['xxx']
123
>>> test['yyy']
KeyError: 'yyy'
>>> test.get('yyy')
>>> test.get('yyy') is None
True
```

And you can check if `'PublicIpAddress'` is absent as follows.

```
ipaddress = instance.get(u'PublicIpAddress')
if ipaddress is None:
   # Do Something
```

**EDIT**

```
if instance[u'State'][u'Name'] == 'running' and instance.get(u'PublicIpAddress') is not None:
    print instance.get(u'PublicIpAddress')
```

Comment: I need to do something like  if instance[unicode('State')][unicode('Name')] == 'running' and instance[unicode('PublicIpAddress')]: 

 then print public IP , how to do so , i understand what u mean here